# SOCP with a norm constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Is it possible to convert this optimization problem into a SOCP:

\begin{eqnarray}
\min && c^T x \\
s.t. && \|A_ix + b_i \|_2 \le c_i^T x + d_i \\
&& \| Dx \|_2 = g
\end{eqnarray}

where $D$ is diagonal. The first constraint is the classic SOCP constraint, but I am not sure whether the second constraint can be converted into a SOCP constraint.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to relax the second constraint to $ \|Dx\|_2 \leq g $?  That would yield a convex problem at least. And then if your minimizer turns out to have norm equal to $g$, then you also have a minimizer for the original problem.

Comment: I think the fact that $\|Dx\|_2=g$ is not a convex constraint dooms you. SOCPs are always convex.

Comment: Both of you are right. This absolutely cannot be represented as an SOCP or SDP, as it is nonconvex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not convex and therefore cannot be represented as an SOCP. However, it is possible to appriximate it using the convex-concave procedure, as described [here](http://ask.cvxr.com/question/28/how-to-handle-nonlinear-equality-constraints/). To summarize, you replace your constraint $||Dx||_2 = g$ by two constraints:

1. $||Dx|| \le g$, which is convex
2. $||Dx|| \ge g$, which is nonconvex

You solve a sequence of SOCP problems, where in each one you replace the constraint (2) by an approximation based on the result from the previous iteration. The approximation is:
$$q^T(Dx) \ge g$$
where $$q = \frac{(D x^{\text{prev}})}{||D x^{\text{prev}}||_2}$$
You can see that the approximation is linear (and therefore convex) and as the difference between $x$ and $x^\text{prev}$ decreases, the approximation gets closer and closer to approximating the original constraint.

Note, that this method does **not** find the global solution. It is just a heuristic.

Comment: +1 for linking to a solution from none other than Stephen Boyd!

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Alex Shtof the link you provide does not exist any more. How to find that post ?